# Yii CJuiAutoComplete default display value and clearing it on click

Tags: autocomplete, yii

I have below CJuiAutoComplete and when loading I want to display "Search" in the text field and on click I want to clear . I tried using "value" under options , but couldn't make it work . Thanks for your help

tried also

`'htmlOptions'=>array('value'=>'Search',)`

```
<?php

$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'test1',
   'source'=>'js: function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
           url: "'.$this->createUrl('myAutoComplete/autoCompleate').'",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {
               term: request.term,
               brand: $("#type").val()
           },
           success: function (data) {
                   response(data);
           }
       })
    }',

     'options' => array(
                    'showAnim' => 'fold',
                    'select' => 'js:function(event, ui){ alert(ui.item.value) }',
                    'click'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                          alert("test");
                                    return false;
                                }',
     ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('value'=>'Search',)
));
?>
```

Regards

**UPDATE**

directly putting 'value' =>'Search' worked .

Checking for click handler

Kiran

Comment: you could also use the "placeholder" attribute in htmloptions, although it's not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you can do is give your widget an id and then you place the `onClick` event in the widget's `htmlOptions` and using JavaScript you clear the value.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'id'  => 'test1_id',
    'name'=> 'test1',
    'source'=>'js: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "'.$this->createUrl('myAutoComplete/autoCompleate').'",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: request.term,
            brand: $("#type").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response(data);
        }
    })
}',
'options' => array(
    'showAnim' => 'fold',
    'select' => 'js:function(event, ui){ alert(ui.item.value) }',
),
'htmlOptions' => array(
    'onClick' => 'document.getElementById("test1_id").value=""'
)
));
```

You cannot put `onClick` in the `options` attribute as these are jQuery options for the [CJuiAutocomplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete), `onClick` is not defined in the [JUI Autocomplete options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-disabled).

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this great solution . I was trying js:function(event, ui) in htmlOptions and it was not working . That is one thing I get basic concepts first :)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but for newbies who land up here, its simple to add a html **placeholder** attribute in Yii CAutoComplete. See code below and add in the htmloptions line:

```
<?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
'model'=>$model,
'attribute'=>'tags',
'url'=>array('suggestTags'),
'multiple'=>true,
'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>50,'placeholder'=>'Seperate tags with commas'),
)); ?>
```